# Jetty not starting on any Port

Tags: maven, unix, jetty, port, ubuntu-18.04

My goal is to run a web application with the jetty maven plugin via "mvn jetty:run".

While it is working on my local machines (iOS, Windows) I can't get it working on my remote VM (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS). I installed a Jenkins Server  via ssh before and it is running on :8080 without problems.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
 <plugins>
        <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopPort>9090</stopPort>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <httpConnector>
                        <!--host>localhost</host-->
                    <port>9090</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     ...
```

(EDIT: I ran following commands via ssh on the vm)
When I call "mvn jetty:run" from the command line , I receive "Port already in use" but I can't see any processes blocking this ports. I tried:

```
sudo lsof -i :9090
```

and

```
sudo netstat -an
```

But can't find any process.

By setting the port to 0, which should choose a random free port, it also says that the "port is already in use".

Is it possible, that the VM is not configured right and "blocks" all ports somehow? If no, what can I do to figure out the problem?

Comment: When you check the ports, are you checking from within that Remote VM?  If not, do so, that will confirm that Jetty is doing it's part, what's left after that is to figure out how to expose those ports outside of the Remote VM. (depending on your VM technology)

Comment: I'm connected via ssh to the vm. I'm running all commands above via this ssh session.

Comment: Go simple first, understand the Remote VM.  Use `netcat` to figure out how port listening functions within that VM (eg: `nc -l 9090` to start a server listening on port 9090) and then outside of the VM attempt to connect to it (eg: `nc <ip-of-remote-vm> 9090` and type a few things).  I say this as Jetty will not start if the configured `ServerConnector` cannot bind, and will complain bitterly (on console and in logs) when it fails.

Comment: Totally forgot to answer: The network where the vm lives in blocked my calls. So the problem was solved.